# VS 2019 Rebuild Deleting Files Needed to Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2019

So this started happening a couple of days ago, it was never a problem before and I don't know what changed.

There's a bunch of pdb, XML, and config files in the bin folder of a project.

When I choose 'Rebuild' on the project, it deletes these files and does not recreate them. This is new behaviour, I don't know why it's happening. It always worked before.

When I then go publish the project, it fails because all of those files are missing.

If I go to the project properties -> Build -> Advanced... -> Debugging information and change it to "None", it does not delete the files on Rebuild, but then the breakpoints in the project are never hit when debugging, which we can't have.

Anyone have an idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the files that were not being rebuilt from the

```
<Compile Include>
```

section in the

```
<ItemGroup>
```

tag in the csproj file.

I have no idea how they got in there, but once they were removed, they started being rebuilt properly.